Can't see Wifi networks on Windows 11 login screen
Situation:
I'm using RDP connection to my desktop PC. That PC is just a PC case connected to a power and a network without LCD screen, keyboard or another phrimentals.
Due to new circumstances I had to switch from a Wired to the WIFI connection. So I installed the Wifi PCI adapter to the PC, I configured a wifi connection include auto reconnection to my wifi network.
Problem:
The problem is that after I restart or power it on the PC it is not able to search or connect to any Wifi network so I can't use RDP connection to that PC:

When I connected to that PC a LCD screen and other pherimentals, I logged user to the Windows and then a Wifi started working and it was able immediately self-connect to a remembered network. Then I've tried to log off user (without restart PC) and Wifi wase still connected:

I also noticed that after I started the PC that LED light on the Wifi PCI adapter was still off when PC was on the Windows login screen. And after I logged into the Windows the LED light started flashing.
Tryies:
I'm not sure if it is an issue with the Wifi PCI adapter so I installed another Wifi m.2 adapter and result was same as with the PCI adapter.
I think it has something to do with the BIOS settings or Windows initialization settings
but I don't know how to deal with it.

I updated BIOS and other drivers via Dell support assistant
I updated PCI & m.2 drivers separately of Dell support assistant

I changed some settings in BIOS like:

disable secure boot
disable fast boot
disable APM/ASPM
enabled Wireles Device
enable Wake on LAN+WLAN

Configuration:

Windows 11 Pro
PC Dell Optiplex 7010
Wifi PCI: TP-Link TL-WN781ND
Wifi m.2: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265NGW

Does anyone have any idea how to make the PCI adapter work after start of PC and before log into the Windows?
Other pictures:





I can't tell from the pictures (W11 user-interface is very bad on given proper visual clues) if you have airplane mode on or off. If it is on, with a manual override to leave Wifi enabled, that override is only valid for the logged-in user. In that case it would make sense that Wifi is disabled at the login screen. You need airplane mode to be OFF.

It's not hard to find that information on google, how does icon looks like when it's ON or OFF. In my case Airplane mode is definitely OFF.

What the icon looks like is highly dependent on the color-schema and display theme in use. On my Windows 11 laptop it looks like that when it is ON. I'm a sysadmin. I deal daily with confusion about Windows 11 indicators in screenshots or when someone is sharing their screen in Teams/Skype/Zoom/TeamViewer, etc. That has gotten me in the habit to always verify what the real state is.
